# T-SQL fulltext catalog search with freetext

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I have a fulltext catalog for an indexed view.

Problem: I want to search with the function 'FREETEXT' all words which contains the search term. But the result doesn't return any entries... but one entry must be the word 'freightcosts'

If the search term = 'freightcosts', the result is 'freightcosts'?

Example:

```
SELECT [Description]
FROM dbo.vuCmsTextDe
WHERE FREETEXT ([Description], 'fre')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a wildcard for partial words, such as

```
SELECT [Description] 
FROM dbo.vuCmsTextDe 
WHERE FREETEXT ([Description], 'fre*')
```